# TreeSet returns false when it should return true?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, treeset

I want to check if a certain `String` is in my `TreeSet`.

It returns `false` when it should return `true`, but I'm not sure where i messed up in my code. Here is the code:

```
HashSet<String> dict = new HashSet<String>();
//TreeSet<String> dict = new TreeSet<String>(dicty);  //snabbare såhär?
int ranNum;
String randomWord;

public AngloTrainer(String dictionaryFile) throws IOException {
    loadDictionary(dictionaryFile);
    System.out.println(dict.size() + " words loaded from dictionary.txt ");
    Random randNumb = new Random();
    ranNum = (randNumb.nextInt(6) + 4);
    //randomWord = randomLetters(ranNum);
    randomWord = "carpatrol";
    System.out.println("The random letters are: " + randomWord);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess a word!");
    //System.out.println(dict.contains("car"));
    //System.out.println(dict.contains("patrol"));
    //System.out.println(dict.contains("rat"));
    while(reader.hasNextLine() != false){
        String gWord = reader.next();
        if(includes(sort(randomWord), sort(gWord))){
            if(dict.contains(gWord)){
                System.out.println("ok!");  
            }else{
                System.out.println("not ok!");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("not ok!");
        }
    }
    //reader.close();
}

private String sort(String s){
    char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(charArray);
    return new String(charArray);
}

private void dumpDict() {
    for(String word: dict){
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}

private void loadDictionary( String fileName ) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
    while(bufRead.readLine() != null){
        dict.add(bufRead.readLine());
    }
    //bufRead.close();
}

private String randomLetters( int length ) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    String letters = "aabcdeefghiijklmnoopqrstuuvwxyyz";  
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(length);
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) 
        buf.append( letters.charAt(randomGenerator.nextInt(letters.length())));

    return buf.toString();
}

private boolean includes( String a, String b ) {
    if ( b == null || b.length() == 0 )
        return true;
    else if ( a == null || a.length() == 0 )
        return false;   
    //precondition: a.length() > 0 && b.length() > 0
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while ( j < b.length() ) {
        if (i >= a.length() || b.charAt(j) < a.charAt(i))
            return false;
        else if (b.charAt(j) == a.charAt(i)) {
            i++; j++;
        } else if (b.charAt(j) > a.charAt(i))
            i++;
    }
    //postcondition: j == b.length()
    return true;
}
```

the `include()` method works fine, it compares two strings to see if the letters in one of them is included in the other one.

```
include("car");    //returns true
include("patrol"); //returns true
include("rat");    //returns true
```

But when entering the words "car", "patrol" and "rat" in the code above, it returns "false" from the `dict.contains(word)`

And all the three words above, is in my .txt file.

Do you have any ideas what went wrong? If you need more of my code, I'll edit it in, just let me know please.

EDIT: Sometimes when I try to guess some words, it return true, but most of the time it returns false (dict.contains()).

EDIT2: Added all my code.

Comment: Which one is returning false? `include` or the current code?

Comment: As a guideline post the minimum amount of code required to reproduce your error.

Comment: Also im curious what `sort` is doing here

Comment: I would also check that the `loadDictionary` loaded what you expected it to have loaded. The TreeSet is unlikely with simple Strings to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Dadani the include method works as it should, its the dict.contain that returns false when i should return true

Comment: @flkes sort() sorts the String in alphabetical order, so "cba" becomes "abc"

Comment: @KevinO loadDictionary() works as it should.

Comment: @CarltonJr., think logically for a moment. What is the probability that a standard JDK library subjected to untold numbers of users and tests would fail?

Comment: @flkes I added rest of my code.

Comment: How big is your dictionary file? If very large, try with a smaller file, just for testing, dump the content of `dict`, and verify it has the right content.

Comment: @KevinO I know the fault is somewhere in my code, not saying the that the problem is because of the standard library. Sorry if it seemed that way, should used other words.

Comment: @Andreas around 10k words. Will try that!

Comment: @Andreas tried with a smaller "dictionary.txt" file, it didnt work either.

Comment: I think loadDictionary is only adding every other line.  The readLine in the while cleause is not added

Comment: @DavidZimmerman Yes, that was the problem I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment:

> loadDictionary() works as it should

However that is entirely untrue. Now that we can see it, we can tell you that it only loads every other word.

```
BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
while(bufRead.readLine() != null){
    dict.add(bufRead.readLine());
}
```

The `readLine()` in the `while` loop reads the first line. The `readLine()` in the `add()` call reads the second line and adds it to `dict`.

**The first line is discarded.**

This repeats such that only even lines are added to `dict`.

Change the code to *remember* the line read by the loop.
Also, remember to close the file, e.g. by using try-with-resources.

```
try (BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)))) {
    for (String line; (line = bufRead.readLine()) != null; ) {
        dict.add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, Thank you very much for the help Andreas!